# OpenCV Merging mask parts within gap threshold

Tags: java, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I'm writing real-time video processing code that uses mog2 algorithm for extracting background from input, then I use morphology filter to smooth it up.

The problem is, that sometimes there are gaps in mask for one object. I think that I could fix it up with some kind of algorithm to fill up gaps within threshold, but is there any algorithm like that in OpenCV, or would I have to write it myself?

Left image is the actual mask, the right one is my paint-made expected result:

[image]

Comment: Can you specify a programming language? Can you provide a few images that present the problem, as well as the desired result?

Comment: Done. Added image to question.

Comment: I feel its because of Shadow.!! Try Bluring of the image initially after capturing.!! or try making luminous value null to some extent this will solve i guess..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About editing your binary mask is a binary morphological operation : You want a `closing` of your binary mask.

[image]

Information about morphological closing is [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/close.htm) (image included)

From the [OpenCV Java documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html) (shortened by me)

> `public static void morphologyEx(Mat src,Mat dst,int op,Mat kernel)`
>
> Performs advanced morphological transformations.
>
> The function can perform advanced morphological transformations using
>   an erosion and dilation as basic operations.
>    [...]> 
>   Note:
>
> An example using the morphologyEx function for the morphological
>   opening and closing operations can be found at
>   opencv_source_code/samples/cpp/morphology2.cpp
>
> - op
>
> MORPH_CLOSE - a closing operation
>
> MORPH_GRADIENT - a morphological gradient
>
> MORPH_TOPHAT - "top hat"
>
> MORPH_BLACKHAT - "black hat"

I don't know enough about the java bindings of OpenCV, but it's probably very similar to the C++ example mentioned in the above quote:

```
// Close the image in C++
cv::Mat element5(5,5,CV_8U,cv::Scalar(1)); # 5 by 5 element set at 1
cv::Mat closed;
cv::morphologyEx(image,closed,cv::MORPH_CLOSE,element5);
```

Comment: That's more or less what I was looking for, not always ideal, but works well enough for my needs.